# CSS overflow only when necessary

Tags: html, css, magento

I have a mini cart on my store that displays all of the products in the basket. I am trying to get the cart's scrollbar to appear when there are a lot of products in the basket so you need to scroll to see them all so the cart remains on the page.

However, the scrollbar is always there even when not necessary and I can't figure out how to stop it from happening. Please see below image:

[image]

Here is the CSS controlling the cart:

```
/* Header Cart */
.minicart-wrapper {/*float: right;*/ position: relative; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}



.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter.empty .cart-full-indicator {display: none;}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter.empty .cart-indicator,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter.empty .cart-full-indicator,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter.empty .cart-full-indicator:after,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter.empty .cart-full-indicator:before {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-full-indicator {
    bottom: 13px;
    display: block;
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-indicator,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-full-indicator,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-full-indicator:after,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-full-indicator:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-full-indicator:after,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-full-indicator:before {
    display: block;
    content: ''
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-full-indicator:before {
    top: -4px
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-full-indicator:after {
    bottom: -4px
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter.empty .counter-number,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter.empty .divider,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter.empty .caret,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter.empty .subtotal {display: none;}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart {
    padding: 10px 8px;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .cart-right-items {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    /*background-color: #000000;*/
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
/*.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .icon:after {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #222;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.56, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.56, 1, 1);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
}*/
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart.active,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart.active .icon:after,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart:hover .icon:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .icon i {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
    /*margin-top: 2px;*/
    color: #fff;
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter.empty .icon {margin-right: 0;}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .text {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .subtotal .label,
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter-label {display: none; color: #fff; }
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .caret {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #aaa;
    margin-top: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .counter-number {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: inherit;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .divider {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4); position: relative; top: 1px; font-weight: inherit;}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .subtotal {
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .subtotal .price-container {display: inline-block;}
.minicart-wrapper .title-cart .subtotal .price {font-size: inherit; color: inherit; font-weight: inherit;}


.minicart-items .product .toggle {border: 0; padding: 0 40px 5px 0;}
.minicart-items .subtitle {display: none;}
.minicart-items .item-options dt {text-align: left;}



.block-minicart .items-total {float: left; margin: 0 10px; display: none;}
.block-minicart .items-total .count {font-weight: 700;}
.block-minicart .subtotal {
    text-align: right;
    border-top: dashed 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 18px 0;
}
.block-minicart .subtitle {display: none;}
.block-minicart .subtotal .price-container {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.block-minicart .subtotal .label {
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 15px;
    top: -3.3px;
    position: relative;
}
.block-minicart .subtotal .price-container .price {display: inline-block; line-height: 1.25em; padding: 0; font-size: 24px;}
.block-minicart .subtitle.empty {display: block; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px 0 10px; text-align: center;}
.block-minicart .text.empty {text-align: center;}
.block-minicart .block-content > .actions {text-align: center; padding: 0;}
.minicart-wrapper .actions div.primary {display: inline-block; float: right;width: 80%;}
.minicart-wrapper .actions div.primary .btn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.minicart-wrapper .actions div.secondary {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; float: left;}
.minicart-wrapper .actions div.secondary .btn {
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #222;
}
.minicart-wrapper .actions div.secondary .btn span span {display: none;}
.minicart-wrapper .actions div.secondary .btn:hover {color: #000000;background-color: transparent;}
.minicart-wrapper .actions div.secondary .btn:after {content: none;}
.minicart-wrapper .actions div.secondary .btn i {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.block-minicart .block-content > .actions .paypal-logo {margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;}
.block-minicart .block-category-link,
.block-minicart .block-product-link,
.block-minicart .block-cms-link,
.block-minicart .block-banners {margin: 15px 0 0; text-align: center;}
.minicart-wrapper:before,
.minicart-wrapper:after {content: ''; display: table;}
.minicart-wrapper:after {clear: both;}
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart {cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none;white-space: nowrap; opacity: 1;}
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:hover,
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart.active {display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);}
.minicart-wrapper .block-minicart {
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    width: 404px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -1px !important;
    color: #666;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 30px 30px 20px;
    display: none;
}
.minicart-wrapper.active {overflow: visible;}
.minicart-wrapper.active .block-minicart {display: block;}
.minicart-wrapper .block-minicart .block-title {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: -.4px;
    text-transform: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    padding: 0 0 9px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.minicart-wrapper .block-minicart.empty .block-title {display: none;}
.minicart-wrapper .product .actions > .primary,
.minicart-wrapper .product .actions > .secondary {float: none; width: auto; margin: 0;}
.minicart-wrapper .action.close {
    background: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
}
.minicart-wrapper .action.close:focus,
.minicart-wrapper .action.close:active {background: none; border: none;}
.minicart-wrapper .action.close:hover {background: none; border: none;}
.minicart-wrapper .action.close.disabled,
.minicart-wrapper .action.close[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .minicart-wrapper .action.close {cursor: not-allowed; opacity: .5; pointer-events: none;}
.minicart-wrapper .action.close > span {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
.minicart-wrapper .action.close:before {
    color: #8f8f8f;
    content: '\0041';
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 'meigee';
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    speak: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.minicart-wrapper .action.close:hover:before {color: inherit;}
.minicart-wrapper .action.close:active:before {color: inherit;}
.minicart-items-wrapper {overflow-y: auto;}
.minicart-items {list-style: none none; margin: 0 0 20px; /* height: auto!important; */ padding: 0; overflow: hidden; /* overflow-y: auto; */}
.minicart-items .product-item {
 padding: 0 0 20px;
 margin: 0;
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
}
.minicart-items .product-item-pricing .label {display: none; width: 4.5rem;}
.minicart-items .options {margin-bottom: 4px;}
.minicart-items .options .list {margin-bottom: 0; text-align: left;}
.minicart-items .price-minicart {margin-bottom: 5px;}
.minicart-items .product-item-name {font-weight: 400; font-size: 15px; margin: 0 45px 6px 0; display: block; text-align: left;}
.minicart-items .product-item-details {padding-left: 75px; position: relative;}

.minicart-items .product-item-details .price-container {display: inline-block;}

.minicart-items .product-item-details .price-including-tax,
.minicart-items .product-item-details .price-excluding-tax {margin: 5px 0;}
.minicart-items .product-item-details .weee[data-label] {font-size: 1.1rem;}
.minicart-items .product-item-details .details-qty {float: left; margin-right: 2px;}
.minicart-items .product > .product-item-photo,
.minicart-items .product > .product-image-container {float: left;}
.minicart-items .product .toggle {border: 0; padding: 0 40px 5px 0;text-align: left;}
.minicart-items .product .toggle:after {color: #8f8f8f; margin: 0 0 0 5px; position: static; }
.minicart-items .product .active > .toggle:after {content: '\e621';}
.minicart-items .product.pricing {margin-top: 3px;}
.minicart-items .product.options .tooltip.toggle {display: inline-block; text-decoration: none;}
.minicart-items .product.options .tooltip.toggle > span {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
.minicart-items .product.options .tooltip.toggle:after {
    color: inherit;
    content: '\e622';
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'luma-icons';
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin: -3px 0 0 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    speak: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.minicart-items .product.options .details {display: none;}
.minicart-items .item-qty {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    background-color: #3eb051;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    min-width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
}
.minicart-items .update-cart-item {font-size: 1.1rem; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
.minicart-items .subtitle {display: none;}
.minicart-items .product.actions {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;}
.minicart-items .action.edit,
.minicart-items .action.delete {color: rgba(0,0,0,.4); /*font-size: 16px; */padding: 5px;}
.minicart-items .action.edit:hover,
.minicart-items .action.delete:hover {color: #000000;}
.minicart-items .action.edit > span,
.minicart-items .action.delete > span {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
.minicart-items .action.edit:before,
.minicart-items .action.delete:before {
    content: '\f040';
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
.minicart-items .action.delete:before {content: '\f1f8';}

/* !Header Cart */
```

Although, I think the most relevant bit is this:

```
.minicart-items-wrapper {overflow-y: auto;}
.minicart-items {list-style: none none; margin: 0 0 20px; /* height: auto!important; */ padding: 0; overflow: hidden; /* overflow-y: auto; */}
.minicart-items .product-item {
 padding: 0 0 20px;
 margin: 0;
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
}
```

When inspecting the element, this appears to be the rendering HTML, difficult to follow as I'm using Magento.

```
<div data-action="scroll" class="minicart-items-wrapper" style="height: 98px;">
        <ol id="mini-cart" class="minicart-items" data-bind="foreach: { data: getCartParam('items'), as: 'item' }">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}} -->
<li class="item product product-item odd last" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product clearfix">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo" href="https://www.bodysocks.co.uk/english/duck-mask.html" title="Latex Duck Mask">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} -->
<span class="product-image-container" data-bind="style: {width: width + 'px'}" style="width: 60px;">
    <span class="product-image-wrapper" data-bind="style: {'padding-bottom': height/width*100 + '%'}" style="padding-bottom: 130%;">
        <img class="product-image-photo" data-bind="attr: {src: src, alt: alt}, style: {width: width + 'px', height: height + 'px'}" src="https://www.bodysocks.co.uk/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/thumbnail/60x78/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/d/u/duck2_2.jpg" alt="Latex Duck Mask" style="width: 60px; height: 78px;">
    </span>
</span>
<!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url --><!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name" href="https://www.bodysocks.co.uk/english/duck-mask.html">Latex Duck Mask</a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url --><!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length --><!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} -->
<div class="price-container">
  <span class="price-wrapper" data-bind="html: price">
    <span class="price-including-tax" data-label="Incl. Tax">
            <span class="minicart-price">
            <span class="price">£12.99</span>        </span>

        </span>

</span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}" for="cart-item-105-qty">Qty</label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty" type="text" size="4" class="item-qty cart-item-qty form-control" maxlength="12" id="cart-item-105-qty" data-cart-item="105" data-item-qty="1" data-cart-item-id="BS-MASK-DUCK">
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }" class="update-cart-item btn btn-default" style="display: none" id="update-cart-item-105" data-cart-item="105" title="Update">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'">Update</span>
                    </button>
                    <span class="hoker-icon qt-x"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit" href="https://www.bodysocks.co.uk/english/checkout/cart/configure/id/105/product_id/302/" title="Edit item">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'">Edit</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}" class="action delete" data-cart-item="105" title="Remove item">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'">Remove</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Hope this is enough to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a place where we can try it out live?

Comment: @PraveenKumar unfortunately not, it's running on a local machine on my network at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

From I can tell it seems that an item has a total height that is bigger then the height of its container. You need to make sure that the container is at least the same height of the item at least when there is only one.

You could just make the items container a littler taller or a better solution is removing the padding from the item when its the first and last item.

Like so

```
.minicart-items .product-item:first-child:last-child{
  padding: 0
}
```

That should probably be enough to make it smaller.

Comment: Thanks, your theory is also that of mine but I just cannot hack a solution together. I have given your code a go and alas, still have the same problem.